# CPU usage to 100% when subclassing node actions

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm designing a game where I want up to 20 nodes, subclassed as LocationNodes, to be spinning around the screen simultaneously. When I call the following function, however, my CPU usage goes to 100% and the app crashes. This is the spinLocations() function, which calls spin on the nodes which are stored in the locationPositions array:

```
func spinLocations() {
    for (key, val) in locationPositions {
        let locationNode = fgNode.atPoint(val) as? LocationNode
        let finalLocation = generateRandomLocation()
        locationNode?.spin(locationNode!, position: generateRandomLocation(), finalPosition: finalLocation)
        locationPositions[key] = finalLocation
    }
}
```

In the subclass LocationNode, the spin function looks like this:

```
func spin(_ locationNode: LocationNode, position: CGPoint, finalPosition: CGPoint) {
    self.run(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.wait(forDuration: 3.0), SKAction.move(to: position, duration: 3.0), SKAction.move(to: finalPosition, duration: 3.0)]))
}
```

How can I rewrite this so it doesn't crash?

Comment: how often are you calling spin?  Sounds to me like you just keep adding and adding and eventually run out of memory

Comment: @amalfilemons You don't need `locationNode` parameter in `spin()` method. You don't use it. Location node in this case is same as `self`.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon This was the answer that was closest. I ran through the trace, and it wasn't that the textures were taking up memory, but that the actions themselves were triggering another function that caused an infinite loop that took up memory.

Answer (score 1):

The function `spin` seems correct but I always prefer to execute it only if itself isn't still running so you avoid to have strangness as miss action executions or displacements of the node not provided:

```
func spin(_ locationNode: LocationNode, position: CGPoint, finalPosition: CGPoint) {
        if self.action(forKey: "spin") == nil {
            self.run(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.wait(forDuration: 3.0), SKAction.move(to: position, duration: 3.0), SKAction.move(to: finalPosition, duration: 3.0)]), withKey:"spin")
        }
}
```

The conditional cast operator `as?` tries to perform a conversion, but returns `nil` if it can't. Thus its result is optional.
You can iterate over the key-value pairs in a dictionary with a for-in loop as you doing but after you should check the kind of *node type* that you retrieve with `atPoint`:

```
for (key, val) in locationPositions {
        let locationNode = self.atPoint(val as! CGPoint)
        if locationNode is LocationNode {
            let finalLocation = generateRandomLocation()
            locationNode.spin(locationNode!, position: generateRandomLocation(), finalPosition: finalLocation)
            locationPositions[key] = finalLocation
        }
}
```